# Logging execution time on Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to log how much time my webapp takes to answer each request.
Right now I have a metaclass for Handlers that wraps each action and calculates the time passed between entering the method and exiting. This works fine, except that the logged times **do not** include the time spent rendering the templates... How could I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the purpose of a tween. It is middleware that wraps the Pyramid application, so it has access to both the ingress and egress of a request within Pyramid. Note that there is already the debug toolbar which displays how long the entire request took. This is also a good application for WSGI middleware of which I'm sure a package already exists or you could easily write your own.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/hooks.html#registering-tweens

Comment: Whoops, there's a timing_tween in the manual itself, completely missed that :D Many thanks!